# Inconsistent results in Tensorflow incremental assignment with scatter_update

Tags: tensorflow

I am using Tensorflow's scatter_update to set the values of an array in a simple test. I would expect the following code to set all values in the array to 1.0.

```
pt = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
numOne = tf.constant(1)
xi = tf.Variable(0)
out = tf.Variable(pt)
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

xi_ = xi + numOne
out_ = tf.scatter_update(out, [xi], [tf.cast(numOne, tf.float32)])

step = tf.group(
    xi.assign(xi_),
    out.assign(out_)
    )
for i in range(15): step.run()
print(out.eval())
```

Instead I get inconsistent results like:

```
[ 1.  1.  1.  0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
```

Is there some type of locking mechanism that I am missing?

Comment: Apart from the fact that your pt is size 16, and you expect to fill 15 values, I think there is something going on with the random order in which the ops are executed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ops inside `tf.group` are executed in random order. If you want specific order, you could use `tf.control_dependencies` or split into two `.run` calls, ie

```
step1 = xi.assign(xi_)
step2 = out.assign(out_)
for i in range(15):
    print(out.eval())
    sess.run(step1)
    sess.run(step2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, using control_dependencies it would be something like:

```
xi_ = xi + numOne
with tf.control_dependencies[xi_]:
    out_ = tf.scatter_update(out, [xi], [tf.cast(numOne, tf.float32)])
    with tf.control_dependencies[out_]:
        step = tf.group(
            xi.assign(xi_),
            out.assign(out_)
          )
       for i in range(15): step.run()
print(out.eval())
```